# Postfix Expression with command line argument, segmentation fault? C

Tags: c, string, stack, command-line-arguments

So I have a program that should be taking an expression as a command-line argument with no spaces, for example:

./program 22+

./program 23+72-*

22+ is also 2 + 2 and 23+72- is (2+3)*(7-2). My problem is that i am getting a segmentation error. Can someone please help me on why I am getting this error? Thank you in advance.

My code (I only have the addition part for now):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    int value[100];
}stack;

void push(stack *pushData, int num);
void initialStack(stack *data);
int pop(stack *popData);

int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
    int i, j;
    int a, b;
    int num = 0;
    stack data;

    initialStack(&data);
    for (i=1;i<argc;i++){
    j = 0;
    while(argv[i][j] != '\0'){
            if(strcmp(argv[i][j],"+") == 0){
                    a = pop(&data);
                    b = pop(&data);
                    num = a + b;
                    push(&data, num);
            }
            else {
                    push(&data, atoi(argv[i][j]));
            }
            j++;
    }

    //printf("%d\n", pop(&data));
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop(&data));

    return 0;
}


void initialStack(stack *data){
    data->top = 0;
}


void push(stack *pushData, int num){
    pushData->top++;
    pushData->value[pushData->top] = num;
}

int pop(stack *popData){
    int n;
    n = popData->value[popData->top];       
    popData->value[popData->top] = 0;
    (popData->top)--;
    return n;
}
```

Edited: Forgot to include my functions

Comment: You do know, do you not, that `*` is a shell metacharacter?  You need to quote it on the command line if you want your program to receive it as itself.  For example, `./program 23+72-\*` or `./program '23+72-*'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
```

That's wrong. Either use `char **argv` or `char *argv[]`, but not `char **argv[]`. Once you fix that, fix your loop to use the right level of indirection (i.e., expect `argv[i][j]` to be a `char`, not a `char*`).

Comment: I'm a little stuck here but, how do you fix the loop to use the right level of indirection?